Python destructing two objects when (I think) I only destructed one
I am learning Python and decided to create a simple class to help me understand. The class is for Tennis Balls.
I have a class attribute of num_balls, and instance attributes of serial_number and age.
I create two instances of the TennisBall class and name them 'a' and 'b'. When I call the destructor for 'a', instance 'b' also gets destructed.
class TennisBall:
    ball_count = 0    
    
    def __init__(self, serial_number, age):
        self.serial_number = serial_number
        self.age = age
        print("New Tennis Ball created {}!".format(self.serial_number))
        TennisBall.ball_count +=1
        
    def __del__(self):
        print("Tennis ball {} has been deleted :(".format(self.serial_number))
        TennisBall.ball_count -= 1
        
        
        

a = TennisBall(1234, 0)
print("Num balls: {} ".format(TennisBall.ball_count))

b = TennisBall(2345, 0)
print("Num balls: {} ".format(TennisBall.ball_count))

del a
print("Num balls after del ball a: {} ".format(TennisBall.ball_count))

I destructed instance 'a' and it was deleted as expected. However, instance 'b' was also destructed, even though I did not call that.
I tried destructing 'b' instead and again both 'a' and 'b' were destructed.

As an aside, I strongly recommend using type hints in your script if you’re new to Python. It doesn’t mean much to the interpreter but tells a lot to a human.

"When I call the destructor for 'a'" - that's not what del does. del a just unassigns a variable. There is no way to manually destroy objects in Python.

This is expected behavior.
When I ran your program, Tennis ball 2345 has been deleted :( appears in the console output after Num balls after del ball a: 1. In other words, the destructor for ball b is called when the program terminates (all objects in memory are deleted).

It is not guaranteed that del() methods are called for objects that still exist when the interpreter exits.
